# PHP Reconstruct array Paypal TransactionSearch Function

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

I am making a call to Paypals API TransactionSearch and I am getting back a flat array of data. I am needing to reconstruct this array. Here is the structure that I get back from paypal:

```
 array(36){
[
    "L_TIMESTAMP0"
]=>string(28)"2012%2d09%2d18T22%3a10%3a13Z"[
    "L_TIMESTAMP1"
]=>string(28)"2012%2d09%2d18T19%3a55%3a41Z"[
    "L_TIMESTAMP2"
]=>string(28)"2012%2d09%2d18T19%3a55%3a41Z"[
    "L_TIMEZONE0"
]=>string(3)"GMT"[
    "L_TIMEZONE1"
]=>string(3)"GMT"[
    "L_TIMEZONE2"
]=>string(3)"GMT"[
    "L_TYPE0"
]=>string(7)"Payment"[
    "L_TYPE1"
]=>string(7)"Payment"[
    "L_TYPE2"
]=>string(7)"Payment"[
    "L_EMAIL0"
]=>string(26)"XXXXX%40hotmail%2ecom"[
    "L_EMAIL1"
]=>string(31)"XXXX%40lvcoxmail%2ecom"[
    "L_EMAIL2"
]=>string(23)"XXXXt%2ecom"[
    "L_TRANSACTIONID0"
]=>string(17)"13E586955G649992Y"[
    "L_TRANSACTIONID1"
]=>string(17)"8LH96897T3119113R"[
    "L_TRANSACTIONID2"
]=>string(17)"87U867057E085230E"[
    "L_STATUS0"
]=>string(9)"Completed"[
    "L_STATUS1"
]=>string(9)"Completed"[
    "L_STATUS2"
]=>string(9)"Completed"[
    "L_AMT0"
]=>string(7)"85%2e00"[
    "L_AMT1"
]=>string(7)"85%2e00"[
    "L_AMT2"
]=>string(7)"85%2e00"[
    "L_CURRENCYCODE0"
]=>string(3)"USD"[
    "L_CURRENCYCODE1"
]=>string(3)"USD"[
    "L_CURRENCYCODE2"
]=>string(3)"USD"[
    "L_FEEAMT0"
]=>string(9)"%2d2%2e17"[
    "L_FEEAMT1"
]=>string(9)"%2d2%2e17"[
    "L_FEEAMT2"
]=>string(9)"%2d2%2e17"[
    "L_NETAMT0"
]=>string(7)"82%2e83"[
    "L_NETAMT1"
]=>string(7)"82%2e83"[
    "L_NETAMT2"
]=>string(7)"82%2e83"[
    "TIMESTAMP"
]=>string(28)"2012%2d11%2d08T14%3a24%3a30Z"[
    "CORRELATIONID"
]=>string(13)"52c22d68648cd"[
    "ACK"
]=>string(7)"Success"[
    "VERSION"
]=>string(6)"51%2e0"[
    "BUILD"
]=>string(7)"4137385"
```

}

I need to reset the array to just the following:
       ["L_STATUSn"]=>string(9)"Completed"
       ["L_TRANSACTIONIDn"]=>string(17)"8LH96897T3119113R"

with 'n' being the number, being the array key number that paypal returns.

Here is the code I am using, and it is borked.

```
        $i = 0;
    $c = 0;
    foreach ($comparison AS $aKey => $v) {
        $findme1 = 'L_TIMESTAMP'.$i++;
        $findme2 = 'L_STATUS'.$c++;
        $txid = $myarray[$findme1];
        $status = $myarray[$findme2];
        $TXid = array_search('$findme1', $aKey);
        $Status = array_search('$findme2', $aKey);
        $TxID[] = array('Status' => $aStatus, 'TransactionID' => $aTransactionID);
        }
```

appreciate abetter way to reconstruct this array, the method I am trying to use doesnt appear to be too efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat late, but maybe others have this request too.  So here goes:

```
function process_response($str)
{
    $data = array();
    $x = explode("&", $str);

    foreach($x as $val)
    {
        $y = explode("=", $val);

        preg_match_all('/^([^\d]+)(\d+)/', $y[0], $match);

        if (isset($match[1][0]))
        {
            $text = $match[1][0];
            $num = $match[2][0];

            $data[$num][$text] = urldecode($y[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            $text = $y[0];
//          $data[$text] = urldecode($y[1]);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Just feed the result from your curl call into this and take the result as a formatted array.

Note the commented out line, there are some fields that are global, such as version, if you want these, uncomment, but then you may have to adjust some formatting code down stream.

if you want to feed this into PHPExcel object, you could do so like so:

```
    $index = 1;
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$index, $row['L_TIMESTAMP'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$index, $row['L_TIMEZONE'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$index, $row['L_TYPE'])
            ->setCellValue('D'.$index, $row['L_EMAIL'])
            ->setCellValue('E'.$index, $row['L_NAME'])
            ->setCellValue('F'.$index, $row['L_TRANSACTIONID'])
            ->setCellValue('G'.$index, $row['L_STATUS'])
            ->setCellValue('H'.$index, $row['L_AMT'])
            ->setCellValue('I'.$index, $row['L_CURRENCYCODE'])
            ->setCellValue('J'.$index, $row['L_FEEAMT'])
            ->setCellValue('K'.$index, $row['L_NETAMT']);
        $index++;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for stopping by, hopefully someone else can use this one